# Unable to decode BSON document to struct

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm having difficulty decoding BSON documents from my MongoDB collection into my Recipe model struct in Go.

I am able to connect to my database fine, and I know my `cursor` is iterating over the documents in the collection- if I print the value of the cursor, I get a BSON document with the information I know is in my database. But when I try and decode `cursor` into the value `recipe`, I get an array of 0s.

I've tried decoding both recipe and the pointer to recipe, but I get the same result.

I've attached the code for both my Recipe model (recipe.go) as well as my repository handling the database interaction (repository.go):

#### recipe.go

```
type Recipe struct {
    id      primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"`
    name    string             `bson:"name,omitempty" json:"name,omitempty"`
    creator string             `bson:"creator,omitempty" json:"creator,omitempty"`
    year    int32              `bson:"year,omitempty" json:"year,omitempty"`
}
```

#### repository.go

```
// Get all Recipes
func (r *RecipesRepository) FindAll() ([]*models.Recipe, error) {
    var recipes []*models.Recipe

    findOptions := options.Find()
    findOptions.SetLimit(100)

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)

    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.D{{}}, findOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer cursor.Close(ctx)
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var recipe models.Recipe
        err := cursor.Decode(&recipe)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        recipes = append(recipes, &recipe)
    }
    if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return recipes, err
}
```

Here are examples of what I get when I print both `cursor` and the decoded cursor `recipe` in each iteration:

```
// log.Println(cursor)

&{{"_id": {"$oid":"5fc98f23df7de068187c78a1"},"name": "Fake name","creator": "Fake Creator","year": {"$numberInt":"2020"}} 0xc0007b4160 0xc0004ff200 0 0xc00014ec40 0xc0003a23c0 <nil>}

// log.Println(recipe)

{[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]   0}

// log.Println(&recipe)

&{[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]   0}
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Capitalize the struct fields. They are not exported, and therefore cannot be marshaled.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I'm glad it was a simple error- I just confirmed it's working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Burak Serdar answered this question in the comments:

> Capitalize the struct fields. They are not exported, and therefore cannot be marshaled